# Cannot import '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module' on Angular 12

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I am currently trying to create a Login Page using Angular 12, and following up, I cannot import the ModuleWithProviders from @angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.

Can you please help me? I searched on the internet but found no solution, or the existing solutions seem not to work.

This is the code:

app.routing.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes);
```

Comment: `import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @AviadP. it's an answer (: go for posting it (:

Comment: I tried, but then it gives me an error at this line export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes); saying that Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders ' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: Agreed @IAfanasov but this particular code has a "smell" - usually you don't export a module as a variable, so I wanted a little more time to think :)

Comment: @lulia can you describe how you got that strange import path? Did VS Code auto generate it?

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is:

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
```

And also, the definition should have a type argument (as you've noticed):

```js
export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes);
```

However, you're doing it wrong - you should either export the route config itself (`AppRoutes`) in your case, and specifiy `RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)` wherever your module is declared (usually `app.module.ts`),

-- Or --

You should define a routing module like the angular cli prepares for you when you do an `ng new` and answer "yes" for routing.